# Storing valuesin a javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays, function

Hello people  here is my code

```
function send(Eqt_Param,Eqt_Param_value)
{
    var Eqt_Paramv=Eqt_Param+'='+Eqt_Param_value;
    alert(Eqt_Paramv);
}
```

every time `Eqt_Param`  and `Eqt_Param_value` will be different ...iam sending values `onclick` so run this script for 5 times well i get 5 different values overall.but now i need to save each value in an array so that i can use the array element in the script function again,

plzz help me to fix this

Comment: In which function would you like to store the values?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = new Array();

function add(param, value){
    var temp = {'param' : param, 'value' : value};

    if (data.length >= 50)
        data.shift();

    data.push(temp);        
}
```

Call the function after the processing like

```
add(Eqt_Param,Eqt_Param_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what u want... but u can try this out..

create a global array...

```
var globalArray=[];
```

use push() to push the values u want in the array

```
function send(Eqt_Param,Eqt_Param_value)
{
   var Eqt_Paramv=Eqt_Param+'='+Eqt_Param_value;
    alert(Eqt_Paramv);
   globalArray.push(Eqt_Paramv);   // i am pushing the result(Eqt_Paramv) here, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a global array variable, and simply assign the function to it.

```
 
  var array = [];
  function send(param, param_value) { 
    array[] = Eqt_Param + '=' + Eqt_Param_value;  
  }
```

or

```
 
  var array = [];
  array[] = send(param, param_value);
  function send(param, param_value) { 
    return Eqt_Param + '=' + Eqt_Param_value;  
  }
```

The array will contain all the results anytime the function is run. 
 
Hope this helps.

Comment: to check the number of elements in the array, try **alert(array.length);**

Comment: why would you want to pass a javascript code to another javascript file? Something's amiss there

Comment: to obtain the values in an array, use something like **for (var i =0; i < array.length; i++){alert(array[i]);}** ; something like that.

Comment: no no iam not passing it to another javascript file,i want to passit to another php file,no issues with that i have tried that method earlier,,, but right now i need to check and make sure javascript array has all the values that i wanna pass,i tried document.write but it is showing [object object]

Comment: even this code for (var i =0; i < array.length; i++){alert(array[i]);} ; is alerting [object][object]

Comment: Check the parameters passed into the function; are they strings?

Comment: change the name, **array** , into something else, probably **array_obj** ;

Comment: hmmm same result.[object object] ;(

Comment: Paste the whole code in http://pastie.org/, and share the link; let's see what you are working with.